# Отслеживание оформления подписки в приложении Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

Как в гугл аналитике отследить оформленную подписку, а не сам факт нажатия на кнопку? (пользователь может нажать кнопку "subscription", перейти в оформление заказа, нажать "назад") Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения Play SDK подписка же выглядит как такой же продукт только с более сложными статусами и дополнительной информацией.

Скорее всего вы должны встроиться в следующий цикл (и вы узнаете о статусе получив финальный Intetn из onActivityResult  :
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api

> To start a purchase request, your application sends a getBuyIntent request, specifying the product ID of the item to purchase, along with other parameters. You should record the product ID when you create a new in-app product in the Play Console.
> Google Play returns a Bundle that contains a PendingIntent which your application uses to start the checkout UI for the purchase.
> Your application launches the pending intent by calling the startIntentSenderForResult method.
> When the checkout flow finishes (that is, the user successfully purchases the item or cancels the purchase), Google Play sends a response Intent to your onActivityResult method. The result code of the onActivityResult has a result code that indicates whether the purchase was successful or canceled. The response Intent contains information about the purchased item, including a purchaseToken String that is generated by Google Play to uniquely identify this purchase transaction. The Intent also contains the signature of the purchase, signed with your private developer key.

Соответственно получив Intent вы анализируете структуру которую вам прислали, смотря на параметры https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference#getBuyInten:

> Table 6. Response data from an In-app Billing purchase request.
>
> Key   Description
> RESPONSE_CODE Value is 0 if the purchase was success, error otherwise.
> INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA   A String in JSON format that
> contains details about the purchase order. See table 7 for a
> description of the JSON fields.

Ну и далее отправляете транзакцию или отмену https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-transactions

```
Product product =  new Product()
    .setId("P12345")
    .setName("Android Warhol T-Shirt")
    .setCategory("Apparel/T-Shirts")
    .setBrand("Google")
    .setVariant("black")
    .setPrice(29.20)
    .setQuantity(1);
// Add the step number and additional info about the checkout to the action.
ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_CHECKOUT)
    .setCheckoutStep(1)
    .setCheckoutOptions("Visa");
HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
    .addProduct(product)
    .setProductAction(productAction);

Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
t.setScreenName("checkoutStep1");
t.send(builder.build());
```